# Help with Spivak's Calculus: Chapter 1 Problem 22

Tags: calculus, analysis

I've tried a lot of things, but I can't seem to get anywhere with this problem. I'm hoping the solution is simple but that I'm just missing it.

The problem is as follows:

> Prove that if $y_0 \neq 0$ and
>
> $|y-y_0| < \min(\frac{|y_0|}{2}, \frac{ \varepsilon |y_0|^2}{2})$
>
> then
>
> $y \neq 0$ and
>
> $|\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{y_0}| < \varepsilon$

I've tried a lot of various things, but nothing seems to get me really any closer.

One thing I think may be related is that you can rewrite

$|\dfrac{1}{y} - \dfrac{1}{y_0}|$ as $|\dfrac{y_0 - y}{y y_0}|$

and from

$|y-y_0| < \dfrac{ \varepsilon |y_0|^2}{2}$ you can say that

$|\dfrac{y-y_0}{y_0^2}| < \dfrac{ \varepsilon}{2}$ which implies that

$|\dfrac{y-y_0}{y_0^2}| < \varepsilon$

So if you can prove that

$|\dfrac{y-y_0}{y y_0}| \leq |\dfrac{y-y_0}{y_0^2}|$ (which may not even be true) then you can prove that

$|\dfrac{y-y_0}{y y_0}| = |\dfrac{1}{y} - \dfrac{1}{y_0}| < \varepsilon$

which all hinges on proving that $|y| \leq |y_0|$, which may not even be true, which would make all my assumptions fall apart.

Also, as far as proving that $y \neq 0$,

I can easily prove that $y \neq 0$ from the first part of the inequality $|y-y_0| < \frac{y_0}{2}$, but I have no idea how to prove it from the other statement that $|y-y_0| < \frac{ \varepsilon |y_0|^2}{2}$.

In any case, I'm convinced I'm going about this the wrong way, and am missing some key observation that would allow me to solve this. Thanks for any help or insight you're able to give.

Comment: Hint: there is a reason they chose $|y - y_0| < \frac{\epsilon y_0^2}{2}$ instead of just $< \epsilon y_0^2$.

Comment: Is y just arbitrary, or is $\epsilon$-close to $y_{0}$, or is there some similar closeness condition on y?

Comment: @SinisterCutlass There aren't any other conditions or stipulations for the question. It just wants you to use the provided relationships.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Sometimes users are incomplete when they write down questions, attempting to paraphrase them from textbooks, so I wanted to make sure.  The solution below looks great.  As for why $y\neq 0$, it should be clear from the problem statement itself.  The consequence of assuming $y_{0}\neq 0$ and $|y-y_{0}|<min(\frac{|y_{0}|}{2}, \frac{\epsilon |y_{0}|^{2}}{2})$ is that $|y-y_{0}|$ is less than BOTH of the elements one takes the minimum of.  Replacing y with 0, it then becomes clear that the assumption precludes this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By triangle inequality
$$\left|y_0\right| = \left|(y_0 - y) + y\right| \leq \left|y - y_0\right| + \left|y\right|,$$
$\left|y - y_0\right| < \dfrac{\left|y_0\right|}{2}$ then implies that
$$\left|y\right| \geq \left|y_0\right| - \left|y - y_0\right| > \left|y_0\right| - \frac{\left|y_0\right|}{2} = \frac{\left|y_0\right|}{2}. \tag{1}$$

Now, apply $(1)$ and the condition $\left|y - y_0\right| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\left|y_0\right|^2$ to the denominator and the numerator in the following expression respectively:
$$\left|\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{y_0}\right| = \frac{\left|y - y_0\right|}{\left|y\right|\left|y_0\right|} < \frac{\left|y - y_0\right|}{\frac{\left|y_0\right|}{2}\left|y_0\right|} < \frac{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\left|y_0\right|^2}{\frac{\left|y_0\right|^2}{2}} = \varepsilon,$$
hence the result follows.

Comment: Would you mind providing some insight on what observations you made to come up with your solution? I understand your solution as I read through it, but when I'm doing these problems myself I find it's hard for me to determine how to add all the pieces together.

Comment: @Shane T Thanks for asking. To large extent, using $\varepsilon-\delta$ language to prove the existence of limit is the combination of algebra simplification and inequality manipulation. Basically you want to control the upper bound of $|1/y - 1/y_0|$, so you want to control the upper bound of the numerator and the lower bound of the denominator, that's how the hint determines that threshold.

Answer (score 1):

*Calculus* is sort of a hobby project for me.  This took many days of puzzling over before I was able to come up with a solution I believe works. Definitely deserved one of Spivak’s ’$*$s’.

I will say at the outset, crucial for me is the fact that $|a-b| = |b-a|$.[^1]  With this fact in hand the solution was considerably easier.  Since I want to refer to this result later I’ll call it $[S]$.

Like the OP I worked backwards and found that,

$$ 
\begin{align}
\dfrac1y - \dfrac1y_0 = \dfrac{y_0-y}{yy_0}
\end{align}
$$

So the game was to see if I could wrangle $\left| y-y_0 \right| < \dfrac{|y_0|}{2}$ and $\left| y-y_0 \right| < \dfrac{\epsilon|y_0|^2}{2}$ into something that looked like the intermediate result,

$$
\begin{align}
\left| y_0 - y \right| &< \epsilon|yy_0| & [M]
\end{align}
$$

The biggest stumbling block for me was that the $y$ and $y_0$ were switched in this formulation.  We are given that $|y \text{ (first) } -y_0 \text{ (second) }|$ in the problem statement.

(I) Considering $\left| y-y_0 \right| < \dfrac{|y_0|}{2}$, we can show that $\dfrac{|y_0|}{2} < |y|$, which I call [A].

$$
\begin{align}
\left| y-y_0 \right| &< \dfrac{|y_0|}{2}\\
\left| y_0-y \right| = \left| y-y_0 \right| &< \dfrac{|y_0|}{2} & \text{[by S]}\\
\left| y_0-y \right| &< \dfrac{|y_0|}{2} &\\
|y_0| - |y| &< \dfrac{|y_0|}{2} &\text{[triangle inequality]}\\
|y_0| - \dfrac{|y_0|}{2} &< |y| &\\
\dfrac{|y_0|}{2} &< |y| & [A]\\
\end{align}
$$

(II) The result [A] allows you to transform $\left| y-y_0 \right| < \dfrac{\epsilon|y_0|^2}{2}$ into our happy intermediate result [M].

$$
\begin{align}
\left| y-y_0 \right| &< \dfrac{\epsilon|y_0|^2}{2} &\\
| y_0-y | = | y-y_0 | &< \dfrac{\epsilon|y_0|^2}{2} & \text{[by S]} \\
| y_0-y | &< \dfrac{\epsilon|y_0|^2}{2} &\\
| y_0-y | &< \epsilon|y_0| \dfrac{|y_0|}{2} &\\
| y_0 - y | &< \epsilon|y_0| \dfrac{|y_0|}{2} < \epsilon|y_0| |y|  & \text{[by A]}\\
| y_0 - y | &< \epsilon|yy_0|  & \text{[M]} \\
\end{align}
$$

… then it’s just an easy stroll to $\left| \dfrac1y - \dfrac1y_0 \right| < \epsilon$.

[^1]:   Maybe this is one of those results that's on the tip of your tongue, but this took me *forever* to see.  I now remember it vaguely from high school and measuring line segments. It’s hardly an intuitive result. I did myself a favour and proved it, a considerably easier thing to do than Q22*.