# Is it possible to find a tighter bound on this inequality from Spivak's Calculus (Chapter 1, Problem 22)?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality

**Problem:** Given that $|y - y_0| < \min \left(\frac{|y_0|}{2}, \frac{\varepsilon|y_0|^2}{2}\right)$, show that $\left|\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{y_0}\right| < \varepsilon$.

I have written solution to this question below, proving a tighter bound of $\varepsilon / 3$. Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Using the first constraint,
\begin{align*}
    |y - y_0| < |y_0|/2 \\
    \frac{|y - y_0|}{|y_0|} < 1/2 \\
    \left|\frac{y - y_0}{y_0}\right| < 1/2 \\
    \left|\frac{y}{y_0} - 1\right| < 1/2 \\
\end{align*}
Using triangle inequality, $\left|\frac{y}{y_0} - 1\right| \geq \left|\frac{y}{y_0}\right| - 1$.

\begin{align*}
    \left|\frac{y}{y_0}\right| - 1 < 1/2 \\
    \left|\frac{y}{y_0}\right| < 3/2 \\
    \left|\frac{y_0}{y}\right| > 2/3
\end{align*}
We'll keep this result in our pocket. Now, let's look closer at the desired inequality.
\begin{align*}
    \left|\frac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{y_0}\right| \\
    = \left|\frac{y_0 - y}{yy_0}\right| \\
    = \left|\frac{y - y_0}{yy_0}\right| \\
    = \frac{|y - y_0|}{|yy_0|} \\
\end{align*}
From the second constraint,
\begin{align*}
    < \frac{\varepsilon |y_0|^2/2}{|y||y_0|} \\
    = \frac{\varepsilon |y_0|/2}{|y|} \\
    < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \left|\frac{y_0}{y}\right| \\
    < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} (2/3)  \\
    < \varepsilon/3
\end{align*}
The second to last line uses the result from the first constraint.

Comment: I cannot see any mistake (except a misprint short before the end: a $<$ instead of a $=$).

Comment: Let $y_0=1$ and $\varepsilon =1.$ For $y={1\over 2}+\delta $ with $0<\delta <{1\over 2}$ the first inequality is satisfied. On the other hand $${1\over {1\over 2}+\delta}-1={1-2\delta \over 1+2\delta }$$ The quantity can be made as close to $1$ as we wish. Therefore it cannot be less than $1/3$ for all $0<\delta<{1\over 2}.$ 

The mistake in the reasoning is located in the penultimate inequality of OP. The inequality there goes the wrong way.

Comment: As @RyszardSzwarc pointed out, what you "kept in your pocket" is "$|y_0/y| > 2/3$", while in the penultimate inequality you claimed "$|y_0/y| < 2/3$", which is inconsistent.  For a correct proof to this exercise, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397569/help-with-spivaks-calculus-chapter-1-problem-22/1397574#1397574).

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake. I cannot necessarily replace the RHS of a < inequality with something smaller. Thank you so much for the help.